# Show that $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and coincides with the Lebesgue set.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu^{*}$ be the Lebesgue outer measure defined as
where $V(B)=C_nr^n$  and $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the family of sets $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an open set $\mathcal{O} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $E \subset \mathcal{O}$  and $\mu^{*}(\mathcal{O} \setminus E) < \epsilon$.
I would like to prove that $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and coincides with the Lebesgue sets. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Is $\mu^*$ the Lebesgue outer measure, or a general outer measure?

Comment: You mean $\mathcal M$ coincides with the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: M coincides with the Lebesgue sets. Edited.

Comment: @Adam it is the Lebesgue outer measure actually.

Answer (score 0):

I consider the case that $n=1$ only. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra
of all Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

$\mathcal{L}\subseteq\mathcal{M}$ follows from the outer-regularity
of Lebesgue measure (which can be found in any real analysis textbook).

To show $\mathcal{M}\subseteq\mathcal{L}$. Let $A\in\mathcal{M}$.
For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, choose an open set $O_{n}$ such that
$A\subseteq O_{n}$ and $\mu^{\ast}(O_{n}\setminus A)<\frac{1}{n}$.
Let $B=\cap_{n}O_{n}$, then $A\subseteq B$. For each $n$, $\mu^{\ast}(B\setminus A)\leq\mu^{\ast}(O_{n}\setminus A)<\frac{1}{n}$.
Hence, $\mu^{\ast}(B\setminus A)=0$. Recall that any set with zero
outer-measure is Lebesgue measurable, so $B\setminus A\in\mathcal{L}$.
Clearly $B\in\mathcal{L}$. Finally, $A=B\setminus(B\setminus A)\in\mathcal{L}$.

Comment: Thanks! Why is M a $\sigma$-algebra then?

Comment: It is because $\mathcal{M}=\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{L}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.